Issue with linux postfix /usr/sbin/sendmail: is there a limit on max number of TO addresses?
I have a distribution list with 101 email address that I use for this command
/usr/sbin/sendmail -bm -v -f'XXXX.SUPPORT@xy.com' -t < /tmp/mailGm8zV8
/tmp/mailGm8zV8:
MIME-Version: 1.0
From: XXXX.SUPPORT <XXXX.SUPPORT.NoReply@xy.com>
Subject: test
To: stefano.rXYZXYZi@xy.com; dummy.001-66751d212b69b@xy.com; dummy.002-66751d212b6a6@xy.com; dummy.003-66751d212b6a7@xy.com; dummy.004-66751d212b6a8@xy.com; dummy.005-66751d212b6a9@xy.com; dummy.006-66
751d212b6aa@xy.com; dummy.007-66751d212b6ab@xy.com; dummy.008-66751d212b6ac@xy.com; dummy.009-66751d212b6ad@xy.com; dummy.010-66751d212b6af@xy.com; dummy.011-66751d212b6b0@xy.com; dummy.012-66751d212b6
b1@xy.com; dummy.013-66751d212b6b2@xy.com; dummy.014-66751d212b6b3@xy.com; dummy.015-66751d212b6b4@xy.com; dummy.016-66751d212b6b5@xy.com; dummy.017-66751d212b6b6@xy.com; dummy.018-66751d212b6b7@xy.com
; dummy.019-66751d212b6b8@xy.com; dummy.020-66751d212b6b9@xy.com; dummy.021-66751d212b6ba@xy.com; dummy.022-66751d212b6bb@xy.com; dummy.023-66751d212b6bc@xy.com; dummy.024-66751d212b6bd@xy.com; dummy.0
25-66751d212b6be@xy.com; dummy.026-66751d212b6bf@xy.com; dummy.027-66751d212b6c0@xy.com; dummy.028-66751d212b6c1@xy.com; dummy.029-66751d212b6c2@xy.com; dummy.030-66751d212b6c3@xy.com; dummy.031-66751d
212b6c4@xy.com; dummy.032-66751d212b6c5@xy.com; dummy.033-66751d212b6c6@xy.com; dummy.034-66751d212b6c7@xy.com; dummy.035-66751d212b6c8@xy.com; dummy.036-66751d212b6c9@xy.com; dummy.037-66751d212b6ca@s
t.com; dummy.038-66751d212b6cb@xy.com; dummy.039-66751d212b6cc@xy.com; dummy.040-66751d212b6cd@xy.com; dummy.041-66751d212b6ce@xy.com; dummy.042-66751d212b6cf@xy.com; dummy.043-66751d212b6d0@xy.com; du
mmy.044-66751d212b6d1@xy.com; dummy.045-66751d212b6d2@xy.com; dummy.046-66751d212b6d3@xy.com; dummy.047-66751d212b6d4@xy.com; dummy.048-66751d212b6d5@xy.com; dummy.049-66751d212b6d6@xy.com; dummy.050-6
6751d212b6d7@xy.com; dummy.051-66751d212b6d8@xy.com; dummy.052-66751d212b6d9@xy.com; dummy.053-66751d212b6da@xy.com; dummy.054-66751d212b6db@xy.com; dummy.055-66751d212b6dc@xy.com; dummy.056-66751d212b
6dd@xy.com; dummy.057-66751d212b6de@xy.com; dummy.058-66751d212b6df@xy.com; dummy.059-66751d212b6e0@xy.com; dummy.060-66751d212b6e1@xy.com; dummy.061-66751d212b6e2@xy.com; dummy.062-66751d212b6e3@st.co
m; dummy.063-66751d212b6e4@xy.com; dummy.064-66751d212b6e5@xy.com; dummy.065-66751d212b6e6@xy.com; dummy.066-66751d212b6e7@xy.com; dummy.067-66751d212b6e8@xy.com; dummy.068-66751d212b6e9@xy.com; dummy.
069-66751d212b6ea@xy.com; dummy.070-66751d212b6eb@xy.com; dummy.071-66751d212b6ec@xy.com; dummy.072-66751d212b6ed@xy.com; dummy.073-66751d212b6ee@xy.com; dummy.074-66751d212b6ef@xy.com; dummy.075-66751
d212b6f0@xy.com; dummy.076-66751d212b6f1@xy.com; dummy.077-66751d212b6f2@xy.com; dummy.078-66751d212b6f3@xy.com; dummy.079-66751d212b6f4@xy.com; dummy.080-66751d212b6f5@xy.com; dummy.081-66751d212b6f6@
xy.com; dummy.082-66751d212b6f7@xy.com; dummy.083-66751d212b6f8@xy.com; dummy.084-66751d212b6f9@xy.com; dummy.085-66751d212b6fa@xy.com; dummy.086-66751d212b6fb@xy.com; dummy.087-66751d212b6fc@xy.com; d
ummy.088-66751d212b6fd@xy.com; dummy.089-66751d212b6fe@xy.com; dummy.090-66751d212b6ff@xy.com; dummy.091-66751d212b700@xy.com; dummy.092-66751d212b701@xy.com; dummy.093-66751d212b702@xy.com; dummy.094-
66751d212b703@xy.com; dummy.095-66751d212b704@xy.com; dummy.096-66751d212b706@xy.com; dummy.097-66751d212b707@xy.com; dummy.098-66751d212b708@xy.com; dummy.099-66751d212b709@xy.com; dummy.100-66751d212
b70a@xy.com
Content-Type: MULTIPART/mixed; charset="iso-8859-1"; BOUNDARY=4ea15edfb62daf8a1491f8d96d62a7a8

--4ea15edfb62daf8a1491f8d96d62a7a8
Content-Type: TEXT/plain; charset=us-ascii

Example Mail
.

For an unkown reason the distribution list is broken as "empty spaces" are inserted automatically on

dummy.031 -66751d212b6c4@xy.com;
dummy.062-6675 1d212b6e3@xy.com;
dummy.093-66751d212 b702@xy.com;

Stefano RADAELLI <stefano.radaelli@xy.com>; dummy.001-66751d212b69b@xy.com; dummy.002-66751d212b6a6@xy.com; dummy.003-66751d212b6a7@xy.com; dummy.004-66751d212b6a8@xy.com; dummy.005-66751d212b6a9@xy.com; dummy.006-66751d212b6aa@xy.com; dummy.007-66751d212b6ab@xy.com; dummy.008-66751d212b6ac@xy.com; dummy.009-66751d212b6ad@xy.com; dummy.010-66751d212b6af@xy.com; dummy.011-66751d212b6b0@xy.com; dummy.012-66751d212b6b1@xy.com; dummy.013-66751d212b6b2@xy.com; dummy.014-66751d212b6b3@xy.com; dummy.015-66751d212b6b4@xy.com; dummy.016-66751d212b6b5@xy.com; dummy.017-66751d212b6b6@xy.com; dummy.018-66751d212b6b7@xy.com; dummy.019-66751d212b6b8@xy.com; dummy.020-66751d212b6b9@xy.com; dummy.021-66751d212b6ba@xy.com; dummy.022-66751d212b6bb@xy.com; dummy.023-66751d212b6bc@xy.com; dummy.024-66751d212b6bd@xy.com; dummy.025-66751d212b6be@xy.com; dummy.026-66751d212b6bf@xy.com; dummy.027-66751d212b6c0@xy.com; dummy.028-66751d212b6c1@xy.com; dummy.029-66751d212b6c2@xy.com; dummy.030-66751d212b6c3@xy.com; dummy.031 -66751d212b6c4@xy.com;

(a the end of this string)
dummy.032-66751d212b6c5@xy.com; dummy.033-66751d212b6c6@xy.com; dummy.034-66751d212b6c7@xy.com; dummy.035-66751d212b6c8@xy.com; dummy.036-66751d212b6c9@xy.com; dummy.037-66751d212b6ca@xy.com; dummy.038-66751d212b6cb@xy.com; dummy.039-66751d212b6cc@xy.com; dummy.040-66751d212b6cd@xy.com; dummy.041-66751d212b6ce@xy.com; dummy.042-66751d212b6cf@xy.com; dummy.043-66751d212b6d0@xy.com; dummy.044-66751d212b6d1@xy.com; dummy.045-66751d212b6d2@xy.com; dummy.046-66751d212b6d3@xy.com; dummy.047-66751d212b6d4@xy.com; dummy.048-66751d212b6d5@xy.com; dummy.049-66751d212b6d6@xy.com; dummy.050-66751d212b6d7@xy.com; dummy.051-66751d212b6d8@xy.com; dummy.052-66751d212b6d9@xy.com; dummy.053-66751d212b6da@xy.com; dummy.054-66751d212b6db@xy.com; dummy.055-66751d212b6dc@xy.com; dummy.056-66751d212b6dd@xy.com; dummy.057-66751d212b6de@xy.com; dummy.058-66751d212b6df@xy.com; dummy.059-66751d212b6e0@xy.com; dummy.060-66751d212b6e1@xy.com; dummy.061-66751d212b6e2@xy.com; dummy.062-6675 1d212b6e3@xy.com;

(and here)
dummy.063-66751d212b6e4@xy.com; dummy.064-66751d212b6e5@xy.com; dummy.065-66751d212b6e6@xy.com; dummy.066-66751d212b6e7@xy.com; dummy.067-66751d212b6e8@xy.com; dummy.068-66751d212b6e9@xy.com; dummy.069-66751d212b6ea@xy.com; dummy.070-66751d212b6eb@xy.com; dummy.071-66751d212b6ec@xy.com; dummy.072-66751d212b6ed@xy.com; dummy.073-66751d212b6ee@xy.com; dummy.074-66751d212b6ef@xy.com; dummy.075-66751d212b6f0@xy.com; dummy.076-66751d212b6f1@xy.com; dummy.077-66751d212b6f2@xy.com; dummy.078-66751d212b6f3@xy.com; dummy.079-66751d212b6f4@xy.com; dummy.080-66751d212b6f5@xy.com; dummy.081-66751d212b6f6@xy.com; dummy.082-66751d212b6f7@xy.com; dummy.083-66751d212b6f8@xy.com; dummy.084-66751d212b6f9@xy.com; dummy.085-66751d212b6fa@xy.com; dummy.086-66751d212b6fb@xy.com; dummy.087-66751d212b6fc@xy.com; dummy.088-66751d212b6fd@xy.com; dummy.089-66751d212b6fe@xy.com; dummy.090-66751d212b6ff@xy.com; dummy.091-66751d212b700@xy.com; dummy.092-66751d212b701@xy.com; dummy.093-66751d212 b702@xy.com;

(and here)
dummy.094-66751d212b703@xy.com; dummy.095-66751d212b704@xy.com; dummy.096-66751d212b706@xy.com; dummy.097-66751d212b707@xy.com; dummy.098-66751d212b708@xy.com; dummy.099-66751d212b709@xy.com; dummy.100-66751d212b70a@xy.com

Can anyone help me to understand why it happens and how to avoid it?

Quite likely you hit limit on maximum line length in email or maximum header length.
Alternative fixes to try:

Use multiple To: (or 'Bcc:`) headers e.g. one header per one recipient
Pass recipients via command line instead of headers (limit number of recipients e.g. 50)

